# How would i get the start indexes of all matched keywords from text in Lua?

Tags: lua

```lua
local Word = "yes"
local String = "yes, i said yes"

--how would i output 
--1 (start index for first yes)
--13 (start index for second yes)
```

I tried using string.find() but that only returns one string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple solution using `string.gmatch`:

```lua
-- note: if this has magic characters, you will have to escape them (not the case here)
local needle = "yes"
local haystack = "yes, i said yes"
local first_idx, last_idx
for start_idx in haystack:gmatch("()" .. needle) do
    first_idx, last_idx = first_idx or start_idx, start_idx
end
print(first_idx, last_idx) -- outputs 1 and 13
```

Explanation: `haystack:gmatch("()yes")` iterates over the starting positions (special capture `()`) of all matches of `yes`. We set `first_idx` if it has not been set already and always overwrite `last_idx`.

---

You could achieve this by repeatedly calling `string.find` just as well, but that would require you to juggle indices and is thus slightly more cumbersome.

---

Just for fun, here's a short solution calling `string.find` and `string.match`, leveraging patterns:

```lua
local first_idx, last_idx = haystack:find(needle), haystack:match(".*()" .. needle)
```

In the second pattern, the greedy prefix of `.*` consumes all occurrences of the pattern except for the last. Again we use `()` to capture a position.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, here is a solution with `string.find`:

```
local Word = "yes"
local String = "yes, i said yes"
local k=1
while true do
    local b,e=String:find(Word,k)
    if b==nil then break end
    print(b)
    k=e+1
end
```